# why my temporary file is not writeable in /tmp folder - linux server(centos)

Tags: php, linux, excel

I'm using [php-export-data.class.php](https://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data/blob/master/php-export-data.class.php), in which the temporary file is not writeable and throws some warning

> Warning:
>   rename(/tmp/exportdatauC7PtH,/report/saleslist.xls):
>   No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/excel/php-export-data.class.php on line 60

here is my code:

```
$this->tempFilename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'exportdata');
$this->tempFile = fopen($this->tempFilename, "w");
```

and my line 60 is.

```
rename($this->tempFilename, $this->filename);
```

I tried giving permission `755` and `777` to my `/tmp` directory but the file is not writing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create all intermediate directories.

In order to rename a file to `/tmp/exportdatauC7PtH,/report/saleslist.xls`, you need to first ensure that the directory `/tmp/exportdatauC7PtH,/report/` exists.

Comment: intermediate directories means, please can you explain in deatil.

Comment: `exportdatauC7PtH` and `report` are intermediate directories. Can you perform a `mkdir -p /tmp/exportdatauC7PtH/report` before writing the file?

Comment: yes i had `report` directory with 755 permission. please see [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function in php. And exactly my question is temporary file i.e. `exportdatauC7PtH` is not writing in `/tmp` folder.